# Perl file changes package between / inside functions

Tags: perl

I'm looking at some of our Perl codebase and am puzzled by the use of `package` in some files.

We have a file containing some useful functions, `functions.pl`, which is laid out roughly like this:

```
package functions;
use strict;

sub function_a {
  # code here
}

sub function_b {
  # code here
}

package main;

sub function_c {
  my ($arguments, $for, $this, $function) = @_;

  package functions; 

  # Actual function code here.
}
```

(Function and package names changed, obviously.)

Functions in this file are used in other scripts by `require 'functions.pl'` and then calling `&function_c()` - since the scripts where `function_c` is called do not declare a package, presumably they're in the `main` namespace so don't have to prepend anything to `function_c` when calling it.

`function_a` and `function_b` aren't used outside this file, so presumably keeping the main body of `function_c` back in the non-main namespace means that code in there doesn't have to prepend `functions::` to any calls to them.

Does anyone know why someone might write a script to be require'd in this way, rather than writing it as a module and explicitly importing certain functions?

And I know that there's more than one way to do it in Perl, but is `package` really supposed to be switched around in one file whenever you feel like it like this?

Comment: The TMTOWTDI motto implies someone will do something you really does not like. In this case, it looks like this "something" has already been done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, there's nothing wrong with the code.  The [`package`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) declaration can indeed be used to "switch around" the current package like that.

That said, it's certainly not the *standard* or generally recommended way to do this; as you note, that would be to turn the script into a [module](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) and (optionally) [export](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) the public functions into the namespace where the module is used.

---

One practical use of multiple `package` declarations is in OO code, where you may want to define multiple classes in one file, e.g. like this:

```
package MyClass;

# ... MyClass methods here ...

package MyClass::Helper {
    # ... helper class methods here ...
}

# ... more MyClass methods here ...
```

or, in older Perl versions (< 5.14):

```
package MyClass;

# ... MyClass methods here ...

{
    package MyClass::Helper;
    # ... helper class methods here ...
}

# ... more MyClass methods here ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - I'd seen code like that when searching for this, and agree that it makes sense when you want to keep multiple class definitions together. It was seeing it around just plain functions (that weren't being used with Perl OO) that puzzled me in my example.

Answer (score 2):

One reason could be that the script was originally designed to import functions from different  set of files (eg:function.pl;function1.pl;function2.pl) based on certain user inputs or certain conditions.

This will entail importing the functions at run time and so 'require $function' where $function could be function.pl or function1.pl

Other reason could be that the person was not aware of modules at that time ;)

Comment: This is the only file with this particular functionality, so I don't think it's been done for switching on user input. I suspect "person was not aware of modules at that time" is a lot more likely. :)